# Braintree payments - processor declined(2409) error for sandbox transaction

Tags: php, paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am trying to test out the Braintree Payments sandbox environment and it is working fine for some payments but not all.

In some payments I am seeing the transaction in Braintree but it has an error `processor declined(2409)`

According to Braintree's documentation this means:

> The customer's bank is unwilling to accept the transaction. The customer will need to contact their bank for more details regarding this generic decline.

However, I was using the sandbox and it happens with PayPal and the card numbers provided by Braintree for testing.

It seems to only be happening for larger amounts. Am trying to test this now to see what the cut off amount is or if it is just coincidence. At the moment it is working for payments over 1000 but not over 2000.

Does anyone know if this is some sort of limit in the sandbox or has this happened to anyone before. I am worried this will affect the production environment but cannot test a transaction over 2000.

Comment: you can request BrainTree technical support to increase the price range for testing. They can do it for you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never mind this is expected according to the documentation here https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php

Comment: Even after all these years, you are a life saver. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are a lifesaver, i placed an order in my Magento 2 for total in the range where the processor declines, and after hours of findings, came here and was so relieved by checking the link, Thank you !!